# How count total occurrences of values in a column of lists in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have this dataFrame and I want to count the number of occurrences of dishes within that column is a list.

```
   |preferred_dishes
    ----------------------------------------------
1   |[Comida Variada, Comida Brasileira, Lanches]
2   |[Salgados, Lanches, Comida Japonesa]
10  |[Comida Chinesa, Comida Japonesa]
11  |[Pizza, Comida Brasileira, Lanches]
15  |[Comida Italiana, Comida Brasileira, Fruto...
```

I tried this:

```
test = pd.Series([x for item in df_dishes.preferred_dishes for x in item]).value_counts()
```

Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `explode` to get the same effect with your `pd.Series()`:

```
df.preferred_dishes.explode().value_counts()
```

Output for the include excerpt:

```
Lanches              3
Comida Brasileira    3
Comida Japonesa      2
Salgados             1
Fruto...             1
Comida Variada       1
Pizza                1
Comida Chinesa       1
Comida Italiana      1
Name: preferred_dishes, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is perfect for `pandas >= 0.25` because [Series.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.explode.html) working in later versions only of version 0.25.0. For instance, I am using the pandas version of 0.24.2.

By the way, you can give a try in order to know your pandas and related package versions:

```
pd.show_versions()
```

Hence, you might interested in below solutions without considering pandas version.

```
counts = (df.reset_index(df.columns.drop('preferred_dishes',1).tolist())
    .preferred_dishes.str.replace('[', '')
    .str.replace(']', '')
    .str.split(',', expand=True)
    .stack()
    .value_counts()
    )
counts
```

The output:

```
 Lanches              3
 Comida Brasileira    3
 Comida Japonesa      2
 Fruto...             1
Salgados              1
Pizza                 1
Comida Chinesa        1
Comida Variada        1
Comida Italiana       1
dtype: int64
```

Or, more simply:

```
counts = pd.Series(df.preferred_dishes.str.replace('[', '')
                             .str.replace(']', '')
                             .str.split(',').sum()).value_counts()
counts
```

The output:

```
 Lanches              3
 Comida Brasileira    3
 Comida Japonesa      2
 Fruto...             1
Salgados              1
Pizza                 1
Comida Chinesa        1
Comida Variada        1
Comida Italiana       1
dtype: int64
```